# itextsharp pdfpcell vertical align problem

Tags: c#, itext

How would I make two cells aligned vertically together. Currently, the second cell renders underneath the first cell. The first cell is an image and the second one is a text. Here is my code.

```
    private Document pdoc;
    Font font99 = FontFactory.GetFont("HELVETICA", 60);
    PdfPTable pdfRatingTable = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell pRatCell = null;
    pdfRatingTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
    pdfRatingTable.SetWidths(new int[] { 75, 25 });

    hImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(MapPath("~/Images/fyler3_Rating.jpg"));
    NewWidth = 338;
    MaxHeight = 18;
    if (hImage.Width <= NewWidth)
    {
        NewWidth = hImage.Width;
    }
    NewHeight = hImage.Height * NewWidth / hImage.Width;
    if (NewHeight > MaxHeight)
    {
        NewWidth = hImage.Width * MaxHeight / hImage.Height;
        NewHeight = MaxHeight;
    }

    ratio = hImage.Width / hImage.Height;
    hImage.ScaleAbsolute(NewWidth, NewHeight);
    pRatCell = new PdfPCell(hImage);
    pRatCell.Border = 0;
    pRatCell.PaddingLeft = 20f;
    pRatCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    pdfRatingTable.AddCell(pRatCell);

    pRatCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("405", font99)));
    pRatCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    pRatCell.Border = 0;
    pRatCell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
    pdfRatingTable.AddCell(pRatCell);
    pdoc.Add(pdfRatingTable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your image is wider than the max width of a cell in your table (plus a rather generous padding), so the next cell appears in the next row.

I suggest trying this with a much smaller image (or the same image at a smaller scale) to see if I'm right.

---

Or by "underneath" do you mean that they're both in the same row, but the text appears at the bottom of the cell while the image is in the middle with a 20 point pad around it so the text is entirely below the image?

IIRC, a `Paragraph` will take up the entire cell but a `Chunk` will obey the cells vertical and horizontal alignment settings.  See the comments in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403136/itext-vertical-alignment-not-working-in-composite-mode).

Comment: Hi Mark, I even resized the image to a bit smaller but the right cell still appears to be in the next row. Even i replaced the image with pRatCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("This is a test"))); and the second cell still appears in the next row. Is my width set for the table looks okay?

Comment: I suggest you turn on the cell borders just to be sure it's really in the next row and not just Much Lower (which I'd expect with a 20pt pad).

Comment: Thanks setting the border helped to figure out. I needed some padding on the top of the first cell to align it to the next one. Thanks once again.